# Build RocksDB failed at snappy/snappy.cc:1033:36: error: invalid output constraint '=@ccz' in asm in MacOS while installing substrate-node-template

Tags: rocks-db

I use the [substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template version: polkadot-v0.9.26](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/tree/autoupdate_polkadot-v0.9.26_2022-07-28_10-17-23) for practice.

When I run `cargo build --release`

I got error:
invalid output constraint '=@ccz' in asm : [tag_type] "+r"(tag_type), "=@ccz"(is_literal));

details:

```
Building [=======================> ] 954/964: librocksdb-sys(build)

The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: snappy/snappy.cc:1033:36: error: invalid output constraint '=@ccz' in asm warning: : [tag_type] "+r"(tag_type), "=@ccz"(is_literal)); warning: ^ warning: 1 error generated.

error: failed to run custom build command for librocksdb-sys v0.6.1+6.28.2

Caused by:

CARGO_CFG_TARGET_FEATURE = Some("cmpxchg16b,fxsr,llvm14-builtins-abi,sse,sse2,sse3,ssse3") running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-arch" "x86_64" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-std=c++11" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-o" "/Users/anweshnayak/Documents/projects/polkadot/parity/substrate-dev-hub/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-0e318981b983f350/out/snappy/snappy-sinksource.o" "-c" "snappy/snappy-sinksource.cc" running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-arch" "x86_64" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-std=c++11" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-o" "/Users/anweshnayak/Documents/projects/polkadot/parity/substrate-dev-hub/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-0e318981b983f350/out/snappy/snappy.o" "-c" "snappy/snappy.cc" running: "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-arch" "x86_64" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-std=c++11" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-o" "/Users/anweshnayak/Documents/projects/polkadot/parity/substrate-dev-hub/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-0e318981b983f350/out/snappy/snappy-c.o" "-c" "snappy/snappy-c.cc" exit status: 0 exit status: 0 cargo:warning=snappy/snappy.cc:1033:36: error: invalid output constraint '=@ccz' in asm cargo:warning= : [tag_type] "+r"(tag_type), "=@ccz"(is_literal)); cargo:warning= ^ cargo:warning=1 error generated. exit status: 1

--- stderr

error occurred: Command "c++" "-O3" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-m64" "-arch" "x86_64" "-I" "snappy/" "-I" "." "-Wall" "-std=c++11" "-DNDEBUG=1" "-o" "/Users/anweshnayak/Documents/projects/polkadot/parity/substrate-dev-hub/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/librocksdb-sys-0e318981b983f350/out/snappy/snappy.o" "-c" "snappy/snappy.cc" with args "c++" did not execute successfully (status code exit status: 1).
```

My MacOS version: 10.15.1

```
 cmake --version
cmake version 3.24.1

 clang --version
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.12)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0

 lldb --version
lldb-1100.0.30.6
Apple Swift version 5.1.2 (swiftlang-1100.0.278 clang-1100.0.33.9)

 gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.12)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

 g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.12)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin


rustup show:

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-2021-01-13-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-2021-09-08-x86_64-apple-darwin
nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.63.0 (4b91a6ea7 2022-08-08)
```

Last time  when I practised the node-template, I downloaded the node-template, 4.0.0-dev, branch = "polkadot-v0.9.17". It's ok.

Comment: It looks like your macOS version is too old? Which version are you using? https://github.com/google/snappy/commit/8dd58a519f79f0742d4c68fbccb2aed2ddb651e8

Comment: I append the tool-chain version info. Is MacOS version 10.15.1 too old ?

Comment: Yep. Recommend you to follow this issue https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11860.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I search for half a day. From [here](https://groups.google.com/g/snappy-compression/c/-AVUHVOf_OQ) and [here](https://github.com/google/snappy/commit/8dd58a519f79f0742d4c68fbccb2aed2ddb651e8) I got some information.

I find the exact file of `librocksdb-sys-0.6.1+6.28.2/snappy/snappy.cc` in the help of `CLion` IDE, which is referenced by the current `node-template` project, and change the piece of code:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__) && defined(__x86_64__)    // delete
#if defined(__GCC_ASM_FLAG_OUTPUTS__) && defined(__x86_64__)   // add this line, change the '__GNUC__' to '__GCC_ASM_FLAG_OUTPUTS__'
  // TODO clang misses the fact that the (c & 3) already correctly
  // sets the zero flag.
  asm("and $3, %k[tag_type]\n\t"
      : [tag_type] "+r"(tag_type), "=@ccz"(is_literal));
```

It seems that `librocksdb` reference the `snappy` by the source code. I directly change the code as per the solution [here](https://github.com/google/snappy/commit/8dd58a519f79f0742d4c68fbccb2aed2ddb651e8). Then compile the node-template code, it is successful.

Another way is updating clang to version >=12

Comment: IMHO, it's a bad idea by modifying the source code, which is stored in the `~/.cargo`. You might forget that later. And `cargo clean` can not touch that part. In the `Cargo.lock` other people will see you are still using that version. But in fact, you are using a different code. I still recommend you to upgrade the macOS/clang.

Answer (score 0):

To update c++ command line in Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential clang curl git make git clang curl libssl-dev llvm libudev-dev make protobuf-compiler make clang -y
```

```
$ c++ --version 

c++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```